# Cancel & Dispose CancellationTokenSource in reconfigurable periodic BackgroundService (IHostedService)

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am trying to create a `BackgroundService (IHostedService)` that calls some async business logic periodically. I am also trying to make it reconfigurable: When the settings change, the background service should react.

I read somewhere that when creating linked `CancellationTokenSource` instances we have to make sure to dispose them, otherwise it might result in a memory leak. This is a big concern for me since I am creating a new linked `CancellationTokenSource` after every configuration change. So I decided to create the `CancellationTokenSource` in a using declaration.

I also have to be able to signal cancellation when the configuration changes so I have registered a callback in `IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions>.OnChange(Action<MyOptions> listener)`. This registration is also called in a using declaration so that the listener is unregistered at the end of the iteration. (I am hoping that it would not be triggered after the `CancellationTokenSource` is disposed.)

VS is warning me that the captured variable (the token source) is disposed in the outer scope.

What I would like to know:

- Is there a chance for a memory leak?
- Is there a chance the `OnChange` callback calls `Cancel()` on a disposed `CancellationTokenSource`? Should I be worried about the warning?
- Did I overcomplicate it? Is there a more elegant solution?

This is what I have so far:

```cs
public sealed class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
  private static readonly TimeSpan _checkIsEnabledDelay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1d);
  private readonly IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions> _options;
  private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
  private readonly ILogger<MyBackgroundService> _logger;

  public MyBackgroundService(
    IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions> options,
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
    ILogger<MyBackgroundService> logger = null)
  {
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(options);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(serviceProvider);

    _options = options;
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    _logger = logger;
  }

  protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
  {
    await Task.Yield();

    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      var options = _options.CurrentValue;

      if (!options.IsEnabled)
      {
        await Task.Delay(_checkIsEnabledDelay, stoppingToken);
        continue;
      }
      
      using var iterationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(stoppingToken);
      using var optionsChangedRegistration = _options.OnChange(updatedOptions =>
      {
        if (updatedOptions.IsEnabled != options.IsEnabled
          || updatedOptions.Period != options.Period)
        {
          iterationTokenSource.Cancel(); // VS warns: Captured variable is disposed in the outer scope.
        }
      });

      while (!iterationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

        var businessLogic = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SomeBusinessLogic>();

        try
        {
          await businessLogic.PerformSomeBusinessLogic(stoppingToken);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
          _logger?.LogError(exception, "Failure message.");
        }

        try
        {
          await Task.Delay(options.Period, iterationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
      }
    }
  }
}
```